# How can I fix code folding in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-folding

When opened, Visual Studio Code will show the appropriate vector symbols alongside the line number as usual, but once finished loading the vector symbols that indicate where one should be able to expand or collapse code are gone, and neither clicking the location, outline, nor shortcut keys have any effect.  The vectors and ability to collapse folded code disappear at about the same time as a warning message in the lower right hand corner appears saying "*Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details.*"  Before that I am also getting an error message when things still work that says "*Unable to start MSBuild language server (see the output window for details).*"  (The output window says:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 2/4/2021, 3:58:32 PM\
    Target: d:\Documents\<redacted> Collab\New Macabre Project\New Macabre Project.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\casto\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.5\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 40184

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.9.28307.812 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
            2: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "c:\Users\<redact>\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[warn]: OmniSharp.CompositionHostBuilder
        It looks like you have Visual Studio lower than VS 2019 16.3 installed.
 Try updating Visual Studio to the most recent release to enable better MSBuild support.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to 'c:\Users\<redact>\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "c:\Users\<redact>\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            CscToolPath = c:\Users\<redact>\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = c:\Users\<redact>\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.5\.msbuild
            MSBuildToolsPath = c:\Users\<redact>\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'd:\Documents\<redact> Collab\New Macabre Project'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'd:\Documents\<redact> Collab\New Macabre Project\New Macabre Project.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'd:\Documents\<redact> Collab\New Macabre Project\New Macabre Project.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'd:\Documents\<redact> Collab\New Macabre Project'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: d:\Documents\<redact> Collab\New Macabre Project\New Macabre Project.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'd:\Documents\<redact> Collab\New Macabre Project' on host 27768.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'd:\Documents\Al Petz Collab\New Macabre Project\New Macabre Project.csproj'.
d:\Documents\<redact> Collab\New Macabre Project\New Macabre Project.csproj
c:\Users\<redact>\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1180,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: d:\Documents\<redact> Collab\New Macabre Project\New Macabre Project.csproj
```

.)  For the past couple of months I have been plighted MS language build errors, and while that might be causing me some trouble this code folding problem is new, and I have nothing to go on.

Comment: Have  you tried targeting a different version of the .Net Framework, as suggested by the output window?

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the message "It looks like you have Visual Studio lower than VS 2019 16.3 installed."
I tried to google, and I found [this](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2555).

But in your context is not clear what you are doing and what kind of software you are building; please provide us ( the community ) with a bit more details on what and where you are creating your project (e.g. Unity its version or something else). You can try to google the required version for the engine or the framework you are using.
Please add some more details about the project.

Different engines/programs may require different versions of
Developer Pack or ".NET Core version".

That is why we can only make suggestions in this case.

First of all, I would suggest you close your IDE and do the following steps:

1. Go to [dotnet.microsoft.com](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks);
2. Download the Developer Pack `.NET Framework 4.8` or `.NET Framework 4.7.2` [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLyGD.png)(image down below);
3. Install the downloaded file and try again.

[image: Download .NET Developer Pack Image]

If it does not help you, you may try to update the Visuall Studio to the latest version as it hints to you.

Another way to solve the issues you may try to:

1. Click on "Build", which is in the top menu;
2. Click "Clean Solution";
3. Click "Rebuild Solution".